# What would be the file structure to build areas using Angular 4 just like asp.net

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio-2015

I am developing a business web application with Angular 4 in visual studio 2015, this application according to user access, has several areas to be able to access, that is, if the user is authorized, he could have access to enter the sales area , Shopping, accounting, etc., each of these "areas" has its own menu, etc.
What would be the file structure to be able to fulfill the aforementioned requirement ?.
The idea is to access your own modules and / or components as much as the "areas" that uses asp.net mvc, using angular 4 (front end)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would have a structure like this:

```
app
- shared // shared comp's and pipes
- core // singletons and a module to import into app.module
- user-access // a folder like this for each feature/access level
  - base-component // this would house your router-outlet and navigation
  - components
  - guards // auth guards to prevent access if not authenticated
  - user-access.module.ts // contain routes and declarations for this access group
- app.component.ts
- app.module.ts //etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I am clear these folders that you mention by a subject of basic structure, then the other folders that manage the "areas" where they would, as you would call them, knowing that the scenario are several areas such as sales, etc,?